# React Native code for Columns with Icons on the side?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, components, figma

I am trying to write a custom component for this "table" type Figma design doc. Should be an icon on the left that takes .25 of the row and .75 of the row is text.
And I should be able to duplicate that right under it.
Below is the code that I've tried, but the image and text actually overflow the page, and I suspect I'm using too many "flex"'s incorrectly or there might be a much simpler way to do. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
export function TwoColumnIconLeft (props){
  const title = props.title;
  const subtitle = props.subtitle;
  const body = props.body;

  return (
    <View
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        padding: 20
      }}>
        <View
        style={{
            flex: .5,
            flexDirection: "row",
        }}
        >
            <Image style={{flex: .25}} source={require("./../Assets/watermelon.png")}/>
            {/* <Text style={[{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: .25 }, styles.subTitle]}>{subtitle}</Text> */}
            <Text style={[{ backgroundColor: "blue", flex: .75}, styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View
        style={{
            flex: .5,
            flexDirection: "row",
        }}
        >
            <Text style={[{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: .25 }, styles.subTitle]}>{subtitle}</Text>
            <Text style={[{ backgroundColor: "blue", flex: .75}, styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  );

};[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>

<View style={{flex: .25, flexDirection: 'column'}} > 
    <Image source={require("./../Assets/watermelon.png")}/>  
    <Text style={styles.subTitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
</View>

<View style={{flex:0.75, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
     <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

Hope this helps.